# Xcode - SQLite different rounding between simulator and device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

How is possible that executing this query (I replaced the fields with the used numbers) gives 0.80 on the device and 0.81 on the simulator?

"SELECT 1.15 - round((1.15*30.000000/100),2)"

I really can't figure out. Same code, same databases. Seems that the device round 0.805 to 0.80 and the simulator (correctly) to 0.81.

Comment: Still don't get why the difference between simulator and device.